# Shiny App not filtering using dplyr and %in% operator

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am making an app using the diamond dataset that I'd like to show the full table unless inputs are selected. However, if I select, say, cut by itself nothing appears. Also, if I select a lot of things no additional diamonds appear. Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

diamonds <- diamonds

#Shiny App

ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(2, selectizeInput(inputId = 'carat',
                                 label = 'Select carat',
                                 choices = unique(diamonds$carat),
                                 selected = NULL,
                                 multiple=TRUE)),
        column(2, selectizeInput(inputId = 'cut',
                                 label = 'Select cut',
                                 choices = unique(diamonds$cut),
                                 selected = NULL,
                                 multiple=TRUE)),
        column(2, selectizeInput(inputId = 'color',
                                 label = 'Select color',
                                 choices = unique(diamonds$color),
                                 selected = NULL,
                                 multiple=TRUE))
    ),
    fluidRow (
        column(12, dataTableOutput('data', height = '100px') ) 
    )           
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    df_current <- reactive({
        df <- diamonds%>% 
            filter(carat %in% ifelse(is.null(input$carat), carat, input$carat),
                   cut %in% ifelse(is.null(input$cut), color, input$cut),
                   color %in% ifelse(is.null(input$color), color, input$color))

        df

    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable({

        df_current()

    })
    }



    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am not sure why the reactive function df_current doesn't work correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could change the `ifelse` to `if/else` as `ifelse` requires all the inputs to be same length whereas the `is.null` returns a single TRUE/FALSE.  So, it is better to use `if/else`.  Also, calling `unique` inside `ifelse` is also not a correct way because it changes the length of the argument

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   df_current <- reactive({
    df <- diamonds%>% 
        filter(carat %in% if(is.null(input$carat)) carat else input$carat,
               cut %in% if(is.null(input$cut)) cut else input$cut,
               color %in% if(is.null(input$color)) color else input$color)

    df

     })

  output$data <- renderDataTable({

    df_current()

})
}
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ifelse` doesn't deal correctly with the factor variables and returns the numbers of the factor levels instead of the factor level. You can circumvent this by using `as.character`. Also, I've used `unique` because you don't need the complete column as the return value.

The second issue is that you have a typo in your filtering for `cut` as you use `color` instead of `cut` as the return value.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df_current <- reactive({
    
    df <- diamonds%>% 
      filter(carat %in% ifelse(is.null(input$carat), unique(carat), input$carat),
             cut %in% ifelse(is.null(input$cut), as.character(unique(cut)), input$cut),
             color %in% ifelse(is.null(input$color), as.character(unique(color)), input$color))
    
    df
    
  })
  
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    
    df_current()
    
  })
}
```